# Extracting <a> tags from string and showing them as an actual tag

Tags: python, html

I am currently building a generator of random pawned sites using HaveIBeenPawned API with Flask.

The problem is that their API is returning as description of given data breach text containing anchor tags like this:

[image: screenshot of text that is being returned]

Is there any way to return the text in anchor tags as an actual tag and not string?

I was checking jinja2 documentation and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tag_str = 'Early in .. <a href="http://www.nextgenupdate.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">NextGenUpdate</a>'
BeautifulSoup(tag_str, features = 'html.parser').text
#Early in .. NextGenUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` library to parse HTML to text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("your text here")
```

Then use `find` method to find all the a tags and parse them into text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bs4`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
scraped = BeautifulSoup(<your html code>,'html.parser')
scraped.find_all('a') #returns list of all a tags
```